# Cannot write large raster on disk which is already in memory in R

Tags: r, out-of-memory, raster

I need help how to write a raster on disk using `raster` package.

```
writeRaster(tif, "tif.tif", ...)
```

I get error 
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.3 Gb

I'm trying to set `rasterOptions(maxmemory=1e+07)` but it doesn't help. My raster has 168 Mpx, the largest I've saved is about 100 Mpx. Should I try to use some split function? If so how to merge it afterwards?

Comment: Sounds like you're dealing with rasters large enough that you'll need to start processing them in chunks. If you look at most **raster** package functions, they include a branch (reached by failing a test for `canProcessInMemory`) that does just that, so that they're able to process rasters of any size. For an example, see [this function](https://github.com/JoshOBrien/rasterDT/blob/374e2ade53647c66044ac0275e96df4ec72bc1db/R/subsDT.R#L87-L109) I recently wrote, paying special attention to the coordinated calls to `writeStart()`, `blockSize()`, `getValues()`, `writeValues()`, and `writeStop()`.

Comment: I'm watching this function but no idea how to use it to save 168mpx raster. Btw, I hope replacing `isFALSE` to `!` is correct in the code.

Comment: That code is just one of many possible examples that demonstrates the general strategy for dealing with rasters that are too large to handle all at once in memory. The basic idea is to use `blockSize()` to compute a number of indices to be used in a loop in which you read, process, and write out chunks of the raster. To see what the results of `blockSize()` look like, try it on a smaller raster, as in `blockSize(raster())`. Not saying this is easy, though. Depending on your actual task, there is probably a better pre-existing solution, that itself takes care of these operations under the hood.